# How to Rename Self-hosted Integration Run Time Node

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have configured `Self-hosted Integration Runtime Node` on my local dev machine to connect to `data-factory` in `Azure`.

[image]

I now want it to change to different name for example "DEV-01-Machine" but cannot see any option in Microsoft documentation. does anyone know how to rename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be updated so far,two evidences:

1.Azure Data Factory [IR Node Update REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/integrationruntimenodes/update).

It only supports below parameter.

[image]

You need to provide specific `node_name` to use this `update` api.

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.datafactory import DataFactoryManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.datafactory.models import *

# Azure subscription ID
subscription_id = '***'

# This program creates this resource group. If it's an existing resource group, comment out the code that creates the resource group
rg_name = '***'

# The data factory name. It must be globally unique.
df_name = '***'

# Specify your Active Directory client ID, client secret, and tenant ID
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id='***',
                                          secret='***',
                                          tenant='***')
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

resource_client.resource_groups.get(rg_name)

# Create a data factory
df_resource = Factory(location='eastus')
df = adf_client.factories.get(rg_name, df_name, df_resource)
print(df)

integration_runtime_name = "***";
node_name = "***";
irn = adf_client.integration_runtime_nodes.get(rg_name, df_name, integration_runtime_name, node_name)
print(irn)
```

2.ADF portal.

No any options to update the name.

[image]

BTW,based on my observation,the node name is identified by the local PC name automatically.

[image]

You could try to update PC names to manage the name rule of nodes.

Comment: Thanks for help. Would it be better to uninstall IR and reinstall IR instead of renaming the PC